# How to update mobx store using a slider from Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider, mobx

I've updated my code to use MobX, but I'm having trouble figuring out what to use for the Slider.

in the store I have:

```
  lowValue: "200",
  highValue: "2000",
  updateLowValue: lowvalues => {
    store.lowValue = lowvalues
  },
```

and in the functional component I have:

```
  const ValueLowSelection = () => {
const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);

return useObserver(() => (
  (
    <>
      <Typography id="discrete-slider-small-steps" gutterBottom>
        Low Value: {store.lowValue}
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={store.lowValue} onChange={changeEvent => 
        {store.updateLowValue(changeEvent.target.value)}} 
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-small-steps"
        step={10}
        min={0}
        max={1000}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
      /></>
  ))
)}
```

When I switch it all back to states, it works just fine, but right now it shows up as NaN.  What am I missing?

Thank you

** edit **
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mccarthy-fnup1
Link to CodeSandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [`onChange` function signature in the documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/slider/#props) you will see that the second argument given to the `onChange` function is the value you are after.

```js
<Slider
  value={store.lowValue}
  onChange={(event, value) => {
    store.updateLowValue(value);
  }}
  aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-small-steps"
  step={10}
  min={0}
  max={1000}
  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
/>
```